# Make a query from a function

Tags: php, mysql, function

At the moment I have written a function to check if a order is completely paid. In the function, a second function is used to determine the total order price. In the first function the total order price is compared with all transactions of the order and based on that, the order is paid or not.

Below the mentioned functions. What I'm looking for is a way where I can change the function to a single query. Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM order 
WHERE
  ((Grandtotal - TransactionTotal) <= 0)
```

So that the query returns for example true if paid, false if not paid.

function IsOrderPaid:

```
function IsOrderPaid($order_id){
  $returnvalue = false;
  $ordertotal = CalculateOrderTotal($order_id);

  $sql = "SELECT SUM(amount) AS TransactionTotal FROM order_transaction WHERE order_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($order_id)."' AND status='9'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);

  if(($ordertotal - $row->TransactionTotal) <= 0 ){
    $returnvalue = true;
  }

  return $returnvalue;
}
```

funcion CalculateOrderTotal

```
function CalculateOrderTotal($order_id){
  $sql = "SELECT
            order_id, SUM(total) GrandTotal
          FROM
            (
            SELECT ordering_id AS order_id, SUM(price * quantity) AS total
            FROM order_products
            WHERE order_id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($order_id)."

            UNION ALL
            SELECT ordering_id AS order_id, SUM(price * quantity * -1) AS total
            FROM  rma_products
            WHERE bestelling_id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($order_id)."

            UNION ALL
            SELECT order_id, amount AS total
            FROM order_shipping
            WHERE order_id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($order_id)."

            UNION ALL
            SELECT order_id, amount AS total
            FROM order_service
            WHERE order_id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($order_id)."

            UNION ALL
            SELECT order_id, SUM(amount * -1) AS total
            FROM order_gift
            WHERE order_id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($order_id)."
          )subTable
          WHERE order_id <> 0
          GROUP BY order_id";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);

  return $row->GrandTotal;     
}
```

I know `mysql_*` is deprecated, but that's the next issue.

Comment: why not you make two mysql functions and use them

Comment: Finaly I want to use the result of this query in another query. Now I execute my first query, in the while I make a call to the function. Based on the result, I fill a array with all orders I need.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a SQL question.  It looks like you want to get the totals for your order, and then subtract the total for the transaction to determine if they have paid in full.  Can you do this:

*where $id = your order id...*

```
SELECT 
sum(op.price * op.quantity) as order_products_total,
sum(rma.price * rma.quantity) as rma_total,
FROM order 
left join order_products op on ordering_id = order.order_id 
left join rma_products rma on ordering_id  = order.order_id 
WHERE
order.order_id = $id
```

You could do this for all your `left join` tables (I only did order_products and rma_products as an example) but you could do the same for and order_shipping and the rest.

In your PHP you would get back all your totals, and you could do your comparison statements there (from just one query).